# Git with Xcode, no such file or directory

Tags: iphone, xcode, git

I've been searching around and looking for answers but I haven't found something that works yet.  I apologize if this is easy and someone has already answered this as I'm new to Git.

What happened was there was a branch both my coworker and I were using.  There was a conflict when I tried to commit (I honestly can't remember if it was committing or when I Pulled in her changes).  Basically we were both deleting unused files, images, etc.  I went through the conflicts and I thought I went through it properly accepting both of our changes, but something still might have gotten messed up because I'm getting

```
No such file or directory
```

For a specific image.  These are some of the things I tried, with cleaning and rebuilding after I have tried one of these which have not worked.

```
- Adding the image back to the project (Xcode still thinks its missing and doesn't update it's .xcodeproj)
- git reset HEAD <file>
- git add <file>
```

Nothing seemed to work.  When I try git status, I saw that it is an untracked file.  I then removed it.  I see my .xcodeproj is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$10 says the .xcodeproj doesn't recognize the existence of the image. Git does a very poor job of properly merging the .xcodeproj file, and you will often have to readd files due to a bad merge.

When in doubt, find a past version of your .xcodeproj that works, bring it to your master HEAD, and add the files that are missing from the .xcodeproj.